# Ошибка с node-gyp

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, node-modules, node-sass

Я не до конца понимаю что это за ошибка и на что ругается мой npm.
Давно встречался с этой ошибкой и снёс нафиг node-sass заменив на обычный sass и это помогло. Но не может же так вечно длиться..почему у кого-то работает, а у меня эта ошибка?
Моя версия node 16.14.0
npm: 8.4.1

```
PS I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend> npm i   
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated intl-messageformat-parser@1.2.0: We've written a new parser that's 6x faster and is backwards compatible. Please use @formatjs/icu-messageformat-parser
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated intl-relativeformat@1.3.0: This package has been deprecated, please see migration guide at 'https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/master/packages/intl-relativeformat#migration-guide'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: I:\node\node.exe I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�⮢ � �⮬ �襭�� �� ������. �⮡� ������� ��ࠫ���쭮� ����஥���, ������� ��ࠬ��� "/m".
npm ERR! ����஥��� ���� 04.04.2022 14:19:38.
npm ERR! �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" � 㧫� 1 (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��).
npm ERR! ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
npm ERR!   �������� ���䨣��樨 �襭�� "Release|x64".
npm ERR! �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) �믮���� ����஥��� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) � 㧫� 1 (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��).
npm ERR! �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) �믮���� ����஥��� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (3) � 㧫� 1 (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��).
npm ERR! I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: ������஢���� �஥�� "I:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" �� �����㦥�. �஢���� ���� � ������� <Import> � ����稥 䠩�� �� ��᪥.
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" �����襭� (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮
�砭��) � �訡���.
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" �����襭� (楫��� ��ꥪ�� 
�� 㬮�砭��) � �訡���.
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" �����襭� (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��) � �訡���.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! �� 㤠���� �믮����� ����஥���.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (楫���� ��ꥪ� �� 㬮�砭��) (1) ->
npm ERR! "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (楫���� ��ꥪ� �� 㬮�砭��) (2) ->     
npm ERR! "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (楫���� ��ꥪ� �� 㬮�砭��) (3) ->
npm ERR!   I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: ������஢���� �஥�� "I:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" �� �����㦥�. �஢���� ���� � ������� <Import> � ����稥 䠩�� �� ��᪥.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     �।�०�����: 0
npm ERR!     �訡��: 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ����祭��� �६�: 00:00:00.84
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'I:\\node\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "С:\Python27" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: С:\Python27
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  С:\Python27 Error: not found: С:\Python27
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "С:\Python27". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb check python launcher python executable found: "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.17
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.14.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.14.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi 
npm ERR! (node:688) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.      
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2013',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Влад\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Влад\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Влад\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\Влад\.node-gyp\16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)        
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "I:\\node\\node.exe" "I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-04T11_18_20_369Z-debug-0.log
PS I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend> npm i
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated intl-messageformat-parser@1.2.0: We've written a new parser that's 6x faster and is backwards compatible. Please use @formatjs/icu-messageformat-parser
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.     
npm WARN deprecated intl-relativeformat@1.3.0: This package has been deprecated, please see migration guide at 'https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/master/packages/intl-relativeformat#migration-guide'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: I:\node\node.exe I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�⮢ � �⮬ �襭�� �� ������. �⮡� ������� ��ࠫ���쭮� ����஥���, ������� ��ࠬ��� "/m".
npm ERR! ����஥��� ���� 04.04.2022 14:23:25.
npm ERR! �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" � 㧫� 1 (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��).
npm ERR! ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
npm ERR!   �������� ���䨣��樨 �襭�� "Release|x64".
npm ERR! �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) �믮���� ����஥��� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) � 㧫� 1 (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��).
npm ERR! �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) �믮���� ����஥��� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (3) � 㧫� 1 (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��).
npm ERR! I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: ������஢���� �஥�� "I:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" �� �����㦥�. �஢���� ���� � ������� <Import> � ����稥 䠩�� �� ��᪥.
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" �����襭� (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮
�砭��) � �訡���.
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" �����襭� (楫��� ��ꥪ�� 
�� 㬮�砭��) � �訡���.
npm ERR! ����஥��� �஥�� "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" �����襭� (楫��� ��ꥪ�� �� 㬮�砭��) � �訡���.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! �� 㤠���� �믮����� ����஥���.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (楫���� ��ꥪ� �� 㬮�砭��) (1) ->
npm ERR! "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (楫���� ��ꥪ� �� 㬮�砭��) (2) ->     
npm ERR! "I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (楫���� ��ꥪ� �� 㬮�砭��) (3) ->
npm ERR!   I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: ������஢���� �஥�� "I:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" �� �����㦥�. �஢���� ���� � ������� <Import> � ����稥 䠩�� �� ��᪥.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     �।�०�����: 0
npm ERR!     �訡��: 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ����祭��� �६�: 00:00:00.98
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'I:\\node\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "С:\Python27" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: С:\Python27
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  С:\Python27 Error: not found: С:\Python27
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "С:\Python27". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb check python launcher python executable found: "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.17
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.14.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.14.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi 
npm ERR! (node:13480) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2013',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Влад\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Влад\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Влад\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\Влад\.node-gyp\16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)        
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "I:\\node\\node.exe" "I:\\OpenServer\\domains\\qubiq\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd I:\OpenServer\domains\qubiq\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Вроде как и на pyton 2.7 ругается, что не найден, но я поставил его и добавил путь к нему в path системных переменных.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого была такая ошибка? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную проблему. Достаточно было сменить версию node в моём случае на 14 (была 16).

UPD: 16 требует 6-ю версию node-sass, но там уже проблемы со сборщиками
лучше ставить 14 (найденное мной решение)

В общем-то вот и всё решение. Надеюсь этот ответ поможет вам, ибо я лично потратил в общих чертах около 3х суток на решения с window-build-tools, python2.7 и прочим.

Но про python2.7: Я снёс старый, удалил из "переменные среды->path" пути до него и установил последнюю стабильную версию python2.7
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А после во время установки обязательно указал автоматическое добавление пути к python2.7 (в моём случае это был последний пункт и там стоял крестик)

На установку windows-build-tools я забил, ибо это какая-то мёртвая затея или действительно необходимо сидеть кучу часов в надежде на скачивание.